# unit test failing in java and not sure why

Tags: java

I have a method in class TreeUtils that checks for simalarity of structure between two binary search trees

```
if(root1 == null&& root2 == null)
    {
        return true;
    }
    if(root1 == null && root2!=null){
        return false;
    }
    if(root1 != null && root2 == null)
    {
        return false;
    }

    boolean leftRecurse = similar(root1.getLeft(), root2.getLeft());
    boolean rightRecurse = similar(root1.getRight(), root2.getRight());

    return leftRecurse && rightRecurse;
```

however when I run a unit test on this file it fails. But if I call this method from the main method, it works. Its not a package or scope issue, because the similar method works in the main method. I think it has something to do with

```
 public BinaryTreeNode getLeft() { 
    assert(this.hasLeft());
    return this.left; 
}
```

maybe because this is now a unit test it is calling the assert?
how should I modify my similar method to avoid this.

This is my Unit test

```
public void testSimilar() {
    System.out.println("Test similarity");
    SimpleBST tree = new SimpleBST();
    tree.insert(1);
    tree.insert(2);
    SimpleBST tree2 = new SimpleBST();
    tree2.insert(1);
    tree2.insert(3);
    assertEquals(true, tree.similar(tree2));


}
```

thanks.

Comment: does `this` have `Left` at that point in the execution of the test?

Comment: im not sure, the class I was given had that in it

Comment: its just weird because my similar method runs when not in a unit test

Comment: Try doing `System.out.println(this.hasLeft())` to find out. The fact that you don't know seems to imply you haven't actually tried to debug this yet.

Comment: if I disable the assert then it works perfectly

Comment: That doesn't mean anything. You'll never know why it doesn't work (and we are literally unable to help you) unless you try debugging it to figure out what's wrong. All I can tell you is that `this.hasLeft()` is returning `false` for some reason. It's really up to you to figure out why.

Comment: Wait. Is getLeft() production code? If so, I doubt that the assert is being raised because the VM needs to run with special arguments. Arguments that I'm sure are standard when running JUnit code. (And I see someone has provided this answer just now.)

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have asserts enabled with -ea argument the program will throw an AssertionError if *this* does not have a left child. But by the setup you have, recursively you want to evaluate the left and right child even if they are null. Simply removing the assertion will work.